# Brackets in system() command in R

Tags: r, bash

I have been trying all day to find a way to run this line (which works in bash) in R, and I keep getting errors about the round brackets... I understand that the paste command gets confused when dealing with brackets, but I have tried escaping the brackets, putting them in double quotes like this "')'" but nothing works so I am out of resources. Does anybody have any idea how this could work in R?

```
system(paste("sortBed -i <(awk -v a=1 -v b=2 -v c=3 -v d=4 '{OFS=FS=\"\t\"} {if ($d < 0.5) print \"value\"$a, $b-\"'$d'\", $c+\"'$d'\"}' file.in > file.out", sep=""))

sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason seems to be that the R system() command calls the bourne shell (sh) instead of the bourne again shell (bash). For example, the command

```
> system("paste <(echo 'Hi')")
```

will fail, mentioning the bourne shell in the process:

```
sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

One solution is to print the command in the bourne shell and pipe the output into bash:

```
> system("echo \"paste <(echo 'Hi')\" | bash")
Hi
```

Answer (score 0):

I get the same error as you when running the line from R. As far as I can see there's missing a final parenthesis for the output process substitution in the bash script but adding that doesn't prevent the error. Also the tabulator should be double-escaped to make sure the backslash is passed onto the `awk` script.

One solution that we found out works in this case is to pipe the output from `awk` directly into `sortBed`.

```
system(paste("awk -v a=1 -v b=2 -v c=3 -v d=4 '{OFS=FS=\"\\t\"} {if ($d < 0.5) print \"value\"$a, $b-\"'$d'\", $c+\"'$d'\"}' file.in | sortBed -i", sep=""))
```

We didn't really get the output process substitution to work, so if anyone has any suggestions for that it would be nice to hear.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help ekstroem, I really appreciate it! I don't think this works either unfortunately... I tried after loading the bedtools and I get the same error as you that it cannot find the command, also even if I take out the "sortBed" it gives me the error "system2(paste("awk -v a=1 -v b=2 -v c=3 -v d=4 '{OFS=FS=\"\t\"} {if ($d < 0.5) print \"value\"$a, $b-\"'$d'\", $c+\"'$d'\"}' file.in > file.out)", sep=""))
sh: awk -v a=1 -v b=2 -v c=3 -v d=4 '{OFS=FS=" "} {if ($d < 0.5) print "value"$a, $b-"'$d'", $c+"'$d'"}' file.in > file.out): command not found

Comment: Ok thank you..The simple system command using only awk works... but is there no way to paste the "sortBed -i <(" part in it? It just seems odd...

Comment: Do you even need the output process substitution, or would something like `system(paste(" awk -v a=1 -v b=2 -v c=3 -v d=4 '{OFS=FS=\"\\t\"} {if ($d < 0.5) print \"value\"$a, $b-\"'$d'\", $c+\"'$d'\"}' file.in  | sortBed -i", sep=""))` get the job done?

Comment: yes that works for this command...I have others even more complicated so I am not sure whether I need it anyway but this works! Thanks very much!

Comment: Great. I'll update the answer to reflect our "discussion" here